# SGDClassifier The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class

Tags: python

So I have done everything possible to resolve this error too my immense frustration.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

train_labels_9 = [(label == 9) for label in train_labels_9]
test_labels_9 = [(label == 9) for label in test_labels_9]

sgd = SGDClassifier(max_iter = 1000, tol = 1e-3)
sgd.fit(train_images,train_labels_9)

below is the error
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-8ad0fdf39a29> in <module>
      6 
      7 sgd = SGDClassifier(max_iter = 1000, tol = 1e-3)
----> 8 sgd.fit(train_images,train_labels_9)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in fit(self, X, y, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    741                          loss=self.loss, learning_rate=self.learning_rate,
    742                          coef_init=coef_init, intercept_init=intercept_init,
--> 743                          sample_weight=sample_weight)
    744 
    745 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, coef_init, intercept_init, sample_weight)
    594 
    595         self._partial_fit(X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, self._max_iter,
--> 596                           classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    597 
    598         if (self._tol is not None and self._tol > -np.inf

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\stochastic_gradient.py in _partial_fit(self, X, y, alpha, C, loss, learning_rate, max_iter, classes, sample_weight, coef_init, intercept_init)
    557             raise ValueError(
    558                 "The number of classes has to be greater than one;"
--> 559                 " got %d class" % n_classes)
    560 
    561         return self

ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1 class
```

Comment: `[(label == 9) for label in train_labels_9]`  Those `train_labels_9` contain anything other than 9? Please post some examples of your labels as well.

Comment: @chris , labels = mnist['target'] labels_9 = (labels == '9'), from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_images, test_images, train_labels_9, test_labels_9 = \
    train_test_split(images, labels_9, test_size = 0.15)

Comment: That is not an example. That is just another code that we dont know whats inside :(

Comment: I see, so you want me to explain what the code does? Just need some clarity plz chris

Comment: No. What I (and usally SO) want is for you to post what `train_label_9` is. You can `print(train_label_9)` and copy paste it, or if it is too long, bit of slicing would be even better. For the future reference, reading [How to create Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help you get your answer more easily and faster.

Comment: print(train_labels_9)   it prints [False, False, False] very huge array, train_labels_9.shape it contains (59500,) pixels. I hope this is clearer

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Thremane D. Henry.
I actually encountered similar problem yesterday, you can check `train_labels.shape`, or `np.unique(train_labels)`.

If you print out some of your train data, say `train[5:10]`, and you will find the problem.

They are chars not `int`.

Change your code to `(label == '9')`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your labels are text values, and thus when you execute the below statement, it returns an array containing only `False`.

```
train_labels_9 = [(label == 9) for label in train_labels_9]
```

You can convert your labels into integer using

```
label = label.astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

(label == 9) generates all False vector
it sees labels as '9' (char)

Comment: @neuron If you only see code in this post you have missed something.